# Convert string to XML using .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net

I store the `XML` output to `String` and Again convert this string to XML .I successfully convert `XML` output to String, but i got problem again converting string to XML.

*sample code:*

```
 webservice.Service1 objService1 = new webservice.Service1();
    String s = objService1.HelloWorld();   //Convert XML output into String   
    XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
    xd.LoadXML(s);
```

I use `LoadXML()` method, but i got error

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1 position 1.
```

Its grateful, if any body give right code to convert String To XML in c#.
Thank you,

Comment: Please show value of `s` - there is a good chance that it is not an XML.

Comment: Put the string response from the `HelloWorld()` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use **XDocument**. **XDocument** is better than **XMLDocument**. It is very efficient, simple and easy to use.

Your code :

```
webservice.Service1 objService1 = new webservice.Service1();
    String s = objService1.HelloWorld();   //Convert XML output into String   
    XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
    xd.LoadXml(s);
```

**Solution:**

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(s);
```

Comment: It is unclear why using different XML parser somehow will make some text valid XML (if another parser could not recognize it). Also "thank you notes" are not necessary...

Comment: can you please look into one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55440649/unable-to-get-values-from-soap-response-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

```
      XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
      xd.LoadXml("<root>123</root>");
```

It works.
You should print the `s` value and check it is a valid xml string.